# Loopback JS global error logging

Tags: node.js, error-handling, loopbackjs

How is it possible to configurate global error logging for Loopback application. I also want to log RestApi errors.

I have tried this https://github.com/strongloop/strong-error-handler but didn't manage to get any errors when using RestApi. In RestApi I got 500 errors with message, but those are not shown in error log

Comment: try winston.js, its great.

Comment: I use winston for logging, but how do I intercept all the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this component to log errors in loopback

https://github.com/strongloop/strong-error-handler